# How to connect to a remote file using CData Excel JDBC driver?

Tags: excel, jdbc, cdata-drivers

Using [CData](https://www.cdata.com/excel/) to connect to local excel file with jdbc url below:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:excel:Excel File=C:\MyExcelWorkbooks\SampleWorkbook.xlsx;");
```

Can we connect to a remote file using CData, If so what can be the connection jdbc url?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by remote? Are you referring to an Excel file that's stored at an accessible network location?

Comment: i mean the excel files are on another system(RDP) @JerodJohnson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CData JDBC Driver for Excel is designed to connect to local and network-accessible files. For example, to connect to an Excel file that has been shared on another machine, use a connection string similar to the following:

```
jdbc:excel:Excel File=\\SHARED_MACHINE\SharedFolder\SharedFile.xlsx
```

If the Excel file is NOT accessible to the machine on which the driver was installed, (i.e. only accessible from Remote Desktop) then the CData JDBC Driver will not be able to connect to it.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" XcoreXexcelX190X7052.xtb: System error: \\xx.xx.xx.xxx\ExcelRemote\products.xlsx (The user name or password is incorrect), where can i give username and password?

Comment: The error message you're seeing looks like a Windows authentication error. Does the Windows account running the Java application have explicit access to the remote location?

Comment: i have actually opened shared drive and tried with my  code it worked fine but without connecting to the drive tried to connect from code i get above exception. How can i solve this? @Jerod Johnson